# read specific cells from a range for a custom function google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm making a custom function for google sheets in google apps script and I have the user select a large range for that function (eg. I1:I23). I want the script to go through each cell in the range and check the contents for a specific value. This is my code. It isn't pretty but I will be able to fix it with this answer.

```
function lowerpos(range,value){
var lowest = 0
var cell = //the top cell in the selected range 
  for ( i=1; i>= range.length;i++){//go through every cell in range 
    if( cell.value == value){ //if the value of the cell its on is the same as value
      lowest = cell //set the variable lowest to the cell's row and column
      }
    cell = cell + 1 //go to the next cell
    }
    return lowest
  }
```

This code is going one by one through the cells in the range checking them to see if their value is the value specified by the user. I want it to return the row and column of the last checked cell with the value.

Answer (score 0):

If the range is only one column, you can do the following to clean up your already existing code function:

- Create the variable ***cell*** = range.getCell(i,1); within the for loop, before your if statement.
- Replace *cell.value* with *cell.getValue();*
- Replace ***lowest*** = **cell** with ***lowest*** = **cell.getValue()**;
- Include *break;* in your for loop, within the if statement, below ***lowest*** = **cell.getValue()**; This will exit the loop after finding the exact match.

Comment: Some questions - like this one, where the code doesn't even compile - shouldn't be answered, especially as they age. Further, your answer is very poorly optimized for large ranges. Also note that op's `for` loop criteria have issues.